# How to refer to directory contains Dockerfile in building?

Tags: docker

I have a project file

```
myProject/
....Dockerfile
....dockerize.sh
```

in Dockerfile I have

```
FROM ottogroup/palladium-base:1.0

# run pld-dockerize
RUN chmod 777 ./dockerize.sh && \
    ./dockerize.sh .
```

it gives me error

```
chmod: cannot access `./dockerize.sh': No such file or directory
```

seems to be I can not use . in Dockerfile ? How could I fulfill the reference to build context directory ?

Comment: Read about ADD, COPY and WORKDIR directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file `dockerize.sh` (and other files in the `myProject/` directory) are not available in the container. Use the `ADD` or `COPY` instruction to add any files to the container, then use `RUN` to run your script.